# Does Spec functor sends pushouts into pullbacks?

Tags: commutative-algebra, pullback

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $B,C$ be two commutative $A$-algebras.
Consider the pushout square of ring homomorphism
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A@>>>B\\
@VVV@VVV\\
C@>>>B\otimes_AC
\end{CD}
and the corresponding commutative square of spectrum $\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$
\begin{CD}
\Spec(B\otimes_AC)@>>>\Spec(B)\\
@VVV@VVV\\
\Spec(C)@>>>\Spec(A)
\end{CD}
If $C=A/\mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $A$ or $C=S^{-1}A$ for some mutliplicative system $S$ of $A$, then the square of spectrums is a pullback square.

> If $A\to C$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings then the bottom square is always a pullback?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333736) there is a similar question regarding the spectrum square in the category of sets.

Comment: I think it might be more efficient to turn this question post into one that is answered by the existing answer post. You then could ask the version you want answered in a  new post linking to this one.

Comment: You suggest me to accept the answer below and open a new question with a link to this question?

Comment: Yes that is my recommendation. But if you do so, please edit this post so that it is actually answered by the current answer. I do *not* recommend to accept an answer that does not answer the question as written, instead I recommend to adapt the question to the existing answer. And to then move on to a new post. In this way the new (or always intended version) will get more visibility. (You can leave a footnote in this post that explains the situation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$This is true for all $A$-algebras $B$ and $C$. You can find a proof in any textbook on scheme theory that covers fiber products (e.g. Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Theorem 3.3 in Chapter II). The argument is more or less as follows: It suffices to check that $\Spec(B\otimes_AC)$ satisfies the universal property of the fiber product (i. e. pullback) $\Spec B\times_{\Spec A}\Spec C$. Recall that for any scheme $Z$ and any ring $R$ we have a canonical isomorphism
$$
\hom(Z, \Spec R) \cong \hom(R, \Gamma(Z, \mathcal O_Z)).
$$
Using this and the universal property of $B\otimes_AC$ as a pushout, we have a chain of natural isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
\hom(Z, \Spec(B\otimes_AC)) &= \hom(B\otimes_AC, \Gamma(Z,\mathcal O_Z))\\
&= \hom(B, \Gamma(Z,\mathcal O_Z)) \times_{\hom(A, \Gamma(Z, \mathcal O_Z))} \hom(C, \Gamma(Z, \mathcal O_Z))\\
&= \hom(Z, \Spec B)\times_{\hom(Z, \Spec A)} \hom(Z, \Spec C)
\end{align*}
for any scheme $Z$. This shows that $\Spec (B\otimes_AC)$ satisfies the universal property of a fiber product.

Comment: The fiber product of spectrum in the category of sets?

Comment: No, in the category of schemes.