# Does Spec functor sends pushouts of rings into pullbacks of sets?

Tags: commutative-algebra, pullback

*This question has an aswer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342222) on MathOverflow.*

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $B,C$ be two commutative $A$-algebras.
Consider the pushout square of ring homomorphism
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A@>\beta>>B\\
@V\gamma VV@VVV\\
C@>>>B\otimes_AC
\end{CD}
In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215844) answer it is proved that the corresponding commutative square of spectrum $\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$
\begin{CD}
\Spec(B\otimes_AC)@>>>\Spec(B)\\
@VVV@VV\Spec(\beta)V\\
\Spec(C)@>>\Spec(\gamma)>\Spec(A)
\end{CD}
is a pullback in the category of schemes.

> That square is a pullback in category of sets (or topological spaces) as well?

The answer is affirmative in two special cases:

- if $C=A/\mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $A$;
- if $C=S^{-1}A$ for some mutliplicative system $S$ of $A$.

Note that in both case, $A\to C$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings.

> The assumption that $A\to C$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings is necessary and/or sufficient?

**My try.**
Let $\beta:A\to B$, $\gamma:A\to C$ and $\tau:A\to B\otimes_AC$ and consider the pushout square of commutative rings above.
If $\gamma:A\to C$ is a ring epimorphism, then the right-handed $B\to B\otimes_AC$ is a ring epimorphism as well.
Moreover, it's know that the functions $\Spec(B\otimes_AC)\to\Spec(B)$ and $\Spec(C)\to\Spec(A)$ are injective.
By [Atiyah & MacDonald - ex. 25 pag. 48] we have
$$\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\tau)=\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\beta)\cap\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\gamma)$$
[image]

This proves the existence of a function $h:X\to\Spec(B\otimes_AC)$ and the injectivity of $\Spec(C)\to\Spec(A)$ implies that the left-handed triangle commutes.
*I've troubles in showing that the upper triangle commutes as well.*